# Which has lower power consumption? BJT or MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, bjt

I on a project which is making a device with Arduino with low power consumption.

There are multiple sensors and my plan is to power on and off the sensors when it necessary. So, use BJT/MOSFET as a switch.

When it comes to lower power consumption (low power), which one will be better: a MOSFET or a BJT?

Comment: Please edit your question and add much more detail. What is the sensors supply voltage being switched? What are all the supply voltages available in your system?

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer is - MOSFET are superior to BJT as a load switch for your application.

Long answer comes down to the details. There are varieties of both BJTs and MOSFETs. They have a lot a parameters which should be taken into consideration. But for the Arduino sensor modules application you should really stick to FETs. Just make sure you pick the right parts for your application. It should have low Rds(on). As most of the sensors don't draw too much power you can take a look at so-called logic level MOSFETs with low gate charge and Vgs(th) levels, so you can control them directly from Arduino GPIO pin.

Answer (score 2):

The MOSFET will have less IR drop when 'on' (only Rds(on)) than a BJT (Vce(sat)). Also, the BJT has base current, while FET gate current is essentially zero.

However, when off, the FET might have more leakage than the BJT - check the datasheets of the comparable FET vs. BJT devices.

That said, there are ultra-low power load switches, like this one: https://www.mouser.com/new/texas-instruments/ti-tps22916-load-switch

And this: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd15380f3.pdf

And this: https://www.vishay.com/docs/66597/sip32431.pdf

Answer (score 0):

As you will most likely want to have a common ground potential between your sensors and controller, a low side switch is not appropriate.

Therefore, you need a PNP or PMOS high side switch.

PNP can only supply as much current as allowed by its base current times its gain. Which means that when the PNP is on you will by wasting the max current divided by gain constantly, even when the load does not require the maximum current. This makes the PMOS almost always better.

Another advantage is that the PMOS has a reverse body diode facilitating load discharge. that must be added for the the PNP negating potential cost advantages

Comment: Why is the "low side switch is not appropriate"? Sensor ground can be switched with NMOS too. Especially if we are talking about Arduino modules where it's usually a separate module pin.

Comment: @NStorm I ignored some special cases in which it might be fine. Especially without any specification about the sensor, its data transmission, sensitivity etc. Too much could go wrong, when switching the sensor ground, especially if it transmits an analog signal back.

Comment: It's not a special case. It's pretty common to switch power at the low side with NMOS. You just have to make sure that current can't flow the other way around. Same goes for switching the high side with PMOS. I can say same things can go wrong with high side switching. Image you have I2C slave device you've closed PMOS but the current still flows through SDA/SCL pull-ups and through protection diodes.

Comment: @NStorm: Having a powered I2C bus to an unpowered chip is indeed something that can go wrong with either high-side or low-side switch but (a) it doesn't balance out the other things that go wrong only with low-side switching and (b) it's far far worse with low-side switching, because the path through signal pins to an open-drain driver on the bus has very small resistance to limit current, while the path through pull-ups to a signal pin is limited by the pull-up resistor.

Comment: @NStorm: And that doesn't even consider the many devices that are tolerant of signal pin voltage above VCC when unpowered but intolerant of voltage below ground.